# Filtering Android Connected Tests

Tags: android, junit, android-testing, androidx-test

I have a few "connected" tests that are only relevant to run on a specific device model or on a specific brand and should be skipped on other brands/models.

I may be missing something, but this kind of filtering seems not possible out-of-the-box with AndroidJUnitRunner (by using annotation and/or passing appropriate arguments to it).

So, I was thinking to extend the AndroidX test framework to support this kind of filtering. In the end, I would like to be able to filter test with something like this

```
@TargetDeviceFilter(brand="SAMSUNG",model="XCover3")
@Test
public void myTestToRunOnSamsungXCover3DeviceOnly(){
    ...
}
```

My question: is there any way to accomplish this kind of filtering without extending AndroidX test framework? And if writing my own AndroidJUnitRunner and/or my own annotations is required, how should I start ?

I found a few interesting base classes that I may need to extend like :

`androidx.test.internal.runner.TestRequestBuilder`
`androidx.test.internal.runner.TestRequestBuilder.DeviceBuild`

but as those classes are in a "internal" package: attempting to extend them is probably not a good idea?

Any advice on how to deal with that problem is welcome.

Answer (score 2):

I think, you may use `org.junit.Assume`.
Create a helper class `DeviceHelper` to detect mobile device informations for convenience.
Your test logic will be executed only if the assumption is correct.

```java
@Test
public void myTestToRunOnSamsungXCover3DeviceOnly() {
        // adapt this part to your business need
        org.junit.Assume.assumeTrue(
            DeviceHelper.isBrand("SAMSUNG") && 
            DeviceHelper.isModel("XCover3")
        );

        // i.e. you can filter whatever you want test's according to device sdk_int
        assumeTrue(SomeHelper.getDeviceSdk() >= 21);

        // your test code
}
```